# Heroku push: gzip stdin not in gzip format

Tags: deployment, heroku, gzip, push

When I try to push an update to Heroku in one of my PHP apps I get the following problem:

> Counting objects: 25, done.
>   Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
>   Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
>   Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 1.20 KiB, done.
>   Total 13 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0)
>   
>   -----> Heroku receiving push
>   -----> Fetching custom buildpack... done
>   -----> PHP app detected
>   -----> Run Sitebase buildpack
>   -----> Bundling Apache version 2.2.22
>   
>   gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
>   tar: Child returned status 1
>   tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
>    !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Php app
>   
>   To git@heroku.com:x
>    ! [remote rejected] feature-removeapi -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:x'

Never had this problem before so I totally don't have a clue what the problem can be.
Is it possible that this is a bug on Heroku's side?

If I look in the Heroku logs I also see the following line:

> Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Php app

All help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I my cases that I had this problem it seemed to be a Heroku problem. Just waiting 10 minutes or  so did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

After so many years and still, this issue occurs.
Btw: My fix was to pin to a specific version as mentioned [here](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/robgraeber/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-gulp):

`heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs#v75 -a my-app`

Answer (score 0):

Same issue had occurred for my Java application which was built with Maven.
It got fixed by configuring Java buildpack provided by Heroku (Earlier I was using custom buildpack which used to work on heroku for same application).